# multi-part identifier not bound using an alias: SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am writing a SQL query and receiving an error when I execute the query.

```
SELECT tableA.*, 
A.tableB.Id AS Item,
B.tableB.Id AS Number
FROM tableA
    JOIN tableB AS A
        ON tableA.DefinitionId1 = tableB.DefinitionId
    JOIN tableB AS B
        ON tableA.DefinitionId2 = tableB.DefinitionId
```

This is giving me the error:

```
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 6
The multi-part identifier "tableB.DefinitionId" could not be bound.
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
The multi-part identifier "tableB.DefinitionId" could not be bound.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Invalid column name tableB'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Invalid column name 'tableB'.
```

I am attempting to take 2 columns from tableA and match them to 1 column from tableB. Why would it be giving me this error, even though I am creating aliases for the two options, and what options do I have to solve this?

Comment: If you use an alias then the name is obscured by this alias and you should use the alias instead. So, use `A.DefinitionId` or `B.DefinitionId` instead of `tableB.DefinitionId`.

Comment: A.tableB.Id? what are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your query to:

```
SELECT 
    A.*, 
    B1.Id AS Item,
    B2.Id AS Number
FROM tableA A
    JOIN tableB AS B1
        ON A.DefinitionId1 = B1.DefinitionId
    JOIN tableB AS B2
        ON A.DefinitionId2 = B2.DefinitionId
```

If you've defined an alias for your table, then continue using it all over the query (joins and `SELECT` part)

Comment: Upon doing this, it still errors: "The multi-part identifier "B.DefinitionId" could not be bound.

The multi-part identifier "B.DefinitionId" could not be bound.

Comment: Ah, wasn't using the Alias in the ON statement, Accepting answer due to answering first.